# ezcMail Init in my PHP application

Tags: php, gmail-api, zeta-components

How can I init ezcMail in my php application? I am planning to use this to create raw email messages to be used int he Gmail API. I have the required extensions: SPL and iconv. This has been giving me allot of trouble! I finally got it to load by doing this:

```
require _SITE_ROOT_.'core/class/ezc/'.'Base/src/options.php';
require _SITE_ROOT_.'core/class/ezc/'.'Base/src/struct.php';
require _SITE_ROOT_.'core/class/ezc/'.'Base/src/structs/repository_directory.php';
require _SITE_ROOT_.'core/class/ezc/'.'Base/src/ezc_bootstrap.php';
spl_autoload_register( array( 'ezcBase', 'autoload' ) );
```

There must be a better way... Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you install the zeta components library using the package manager [composer](https://getcomposer.org). It includes an autoloader that will pull in the required classes.